# symmetric DS registration fails on tomcat

Tags: tomcat8, symmetricds

I am trying to run symmetric DS war on tomcat. Below ar the steps I followed :

1. I have created war using this command:
   command: ../bin/symadmin create-war /root/symmetric-ds.war
2. Then I deployed war on the tomcat.
3. When my client node tries to register with master node it gives following 
   error as shown below:

   [SGW-000] - DataLoaderService - Requesting current configuration {symmetricVersion=3.8.28, configVersion=null}
   [SGW-000] - PullService - Could not communicate with node 'null:null:?' at http://10.97.57.75:31415/symmetric-ds/sync because of unexpected error
   java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://10.97.57.75:31415/symmetric-ds/sync/config?nodeId=000&securityToken=07a654896b216bfd6acb9746470f73&hostName=mc-ha-vm1.edcharman.com&ipAddress=10.97.57.74&symmetricVersion=3.8.28&configVersion=
   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1926)
   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1921)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1920)
   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1490)
   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
   at org.jumpmind.symmetric.transport.http.HttpTransportManager.getInputStreamFrom(HttpTransportManager.java:301)
   at org.jumpmind.symmetric.transport.http.HttpIncomingTransport.openStream(HttpIncomingTransport.java:118)
   at org.jumpmind.symmetric.transport.http.HttpIncomingTransport.openReader(HttpIncomingTransport.java:125)
   at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.DataLoaderService.loadDataFromTransport(DataLoaderService.java:554)
   at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.DataLoaderService.loadDataFromConfig(DataLoaderService.java:487)
   at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.PullService.pullConfigData(PullService.java:170)
   at org.jumpmind.symmetric.AbstractSymmetricEngine.start(AbstractSymmetricEngine.java:623)
   at org.jumpmind.symmetric.AbstractSymmetricEngine.start(AbstractSymmetricEngine.java:571)
   at org.jumpmind.symmetric.ClientSymmetricEngine.start(ClientSymmetricEngine.java:244)
   at org.jumpmind.symmetric.web.SymmetricEngineHolder$EngineStarter.run(SymmetricEngineHolder.java:524)
   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for 
   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1876)
   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
   at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
   at org.jumpmind.symmetric.transport.http.HttpIncomingTransport.openConnectionCheckRedirects(HttpIncomingTransport.java:159)
   at org.jumpmind.symmetric.transport.http.HttpIncomingTransport.openStream(HttpIncomingTransport.java:99)
   ... 8 more

Can anyone please help here ?

Comment: What's the configuration of sync.url at the client?

Comment: Thanks for giving attention. My sync URL  is:

Comment: The URL is missing

Comment: Thanks for giving attention. My sync URL  is:  
http://10.97.57.75:31415/symmetric-ds/sync
I found my mistake I was giving wrong external id in open registration command.
../bin/symadmin --engine MC-000 open-registration SGW 001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think running symmetric DS with Tomcat is little bit tricky for new comers. So I sharing steps that worked for me:

sync url on master node:
sync.url=https://masterNodeIP:31415/warName/sync

register url on client node: 
sync.url=https://masterNodeIP:31415/warName/sync

1. Go to symmetric-ds-3.x.x-server/bin folder and create symmetric-ds.war: 
   ./symadmin create-war /Path of war/symmetric-ds.war
2. Copy war to /tomcat/webeapps folder.
3. copy postgresql-9.4-1212.jre7.jar file from ~/symmetric-server-3.8.28/lib to 
   ~/apache-tomcat-8.0.24/webapps/symmetric-ds/WEB-INF/lib folder
4. Do following port configuration in /tomcat.x.x/conf/server.xml
5. Execute below command on master node to open registration:
   master node id: ABC-000
   client node group: XYZ
   Clinet node external id: 001
   ../bin/symadmin --engine ABC-000 open-registration XYZ 001